# Trying to position text within a percentage div vertically centered

Tags: css

I need a button that fits centrally in the screen with the text vertically aligned with the button. This can use CSS only and must only user percentages. Here is my attempt so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/52/

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="button">
        button text
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin : 0px;
}
#outer {
    position : absolute;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    background-color : #123456;
    text-align: center;
}
#outer:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#button {
    height : 50%;
    width : 50%;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: can you use flexbox? http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: are you looking for this http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ IE8+ though

Comment: obviously, everyone here says : use display:table :) and learn to use display flex in futur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nowdays you should use display and keep things in the flow , absolute positionning is from another time :)

so [display:table](http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/54/)

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
html {
    display:table;
}
body {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:#48a
}
#button {
    height : 50%;
    width : 50%;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
/* correction of your use of pseudo element to vertical center */
#button:before {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    ;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And soon : [display:flex](http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/55/)

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    display:flex;
    background:#48a
}
#button {
    height : 50%;
    width : 50%;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
/* correction of your use of pseudo element to vertical center */
#button:before {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    ;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

to apply [flex display to button box too](http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/56/) : add these rules and drop the pseudo element :

```
#button {
    height : 50%;
    width : 50%;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
    /* to center itself in flex box */
    margin:auto;
    /* to center inside content */
    justify-content:center;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

`display:flex;` works fine with latest : Opera, Chrome, Firefox and ie.

`display;table;` works with most of browser and since IE8

Comment: I'm trying to have 3 buttons equally spaces with a 5% gap between them. I've taken your code and create a fiddle. Can you see how to get the gap please http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/66/

Comment: hi, button should be class and inline-block with little less width : http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/69/ or http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/70/ like this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use flexbox, a feasible and clean solution is the following:

add the following to the `#outer` container to center align the button div:

```
#outer {
  ...
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

and then to `#button` to align the text inside:

```
#button {
    ...
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

You also have to remove the `display: inline-block;` inside `#button`.

Working fiddle (tested on FF and Chrome MacOS): http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/53/

For a complete reference about flexbox support check here: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: display:flex + margin:auto on child is plenty enough for one single element to center on both axis :)  i mean for the button box http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/56/ outer is useless by the way in that case

Answer (score 1):

You can also play with display table-cell without using pseudo selectors as follows

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block">
        <div id="button">button text</div>
    </div>
</div>
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid green;
    width:100%;
}
.block {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#button {
    background-color : #f00;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8BJ94/57/